# How to load installed webcams names in Java

Tags: java, webcam

Is there to load the names of the installed webcams on my computer in Java application ?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2011/07/java-webcam-gstreamer/) says that if the webcams are ones that JMF understands then this will list them:

```
Vector info = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
```

The page goes on to talk about using gstreamer-java with webcams that JMF doesn't understand, but I can't see anything there about finding the webcams.